# How to import c# Classes in Python using Python.Net

Tags: c#, python, .net, python.net

I'm using [Python.NET](http://pythonnet.github.io/) to create wrapper for a c# code. I am able to import the namespace but when i import the class, i get the error 'Library' has no attribute 'Wrapper'

```py
import clr
clr.AddReference(r'Library.dll')
from Library import Wrapper
wrapper = Wrapper()
```

```py
dir(Library)
```

Dir command's output does not contain class Wrapper

Here's the C# code-

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace Library
{
    public class Functions
    {
        public double Add(double a, double b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }

    public class Wrapper : DynamicObject
    {
        public Functions functions;
        public Wrapper()
        {
            functions = new Functions();
        }

        public double Add(double a, double b)
        {
            return functions.Add(a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code should work if `Library` is a namespace and `Wrapper` was a public class defined in that namespace. What does the C# code look like?

Comment: Is there a reason why dir(Library) does not return these classes defined in the namespace.

Comment: There's no `dir` in [Python.NET's docs](http://pythonnet.github.io/). Python's `dir` won't work because `Library` is a *namespace*, not an object.

Comment: remove `.dll` extension from assembly name. Add the directory of assembly to sys.path